# Date Filter in java

Tags: java, date, filter

I need to filter a date from the "From date" to the "To date" using the "Current date" filter.

Here is the code I use in my java application:

```
String from = "19/05/1991";
String cmp = "23/05/1991";
String to = "23/12/2015";

if (from.compareTo(cmp) <= 0 && to.compareTo(cmp) >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Date lies between from and to date");
}
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: Sort of, although that answer and the answer it references assumes you have Dates already. A good answer to this one might include why comparing Strings like that won't work (although if the dates were yyyy/mm/dd it would work fine), and how to get a String into a Date.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
String from = "19/05/1991";
String cmp = "23/05/1991";
String to = "23/12/2015";

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = format.parse(from);
Date date2 = format.parse(cmp);
Date date3 = format.parse(to);

if(date1.before(date2) && date3.after(date2)) {
   System.out.println("Date lies between from and to date");
}
```

See [Date#after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and [Date#before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29)